# Linux mint 20 Crash caused my multiple GPU?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, gpu, crash

I need help diagnosing a system crash. I have had 2 crashes since I installed my new GPU on 3/18/2021. I installed a GT710 along side my GTX 1070. Neither of the crash reports indicated anything about it being the GPU.

Any help diagnosing the problem is greatly appreciated. I have been training machine learning models non-stop for a couple of weeks now and it is very frustrating to lose days worth of computations.

My system info is as follows:
[image: strong text]

This is the Output of journalctl:

[image]

When my system crashed the screen was stuck at 11:53 am, but the last log is the DNS failure from 11:50am

Here is the output of my car/log/sys.log.1 when I grep for "error":

[image]

I am going to try and update my NVIDIA drivers and see if that helps. If I have another crash I will update here.

Thank you for any help